# How to get the correct values from a DataFrame using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file taken from [this website](http://techslides.com/list-of-countries-and-capitals). I want to only take the countries, which capitals `lat` and `lon` are visible on the screen.

So if I were to only see the capitals of North America (Mexico, Canada and USA) this is how the bordering values would look like:

```
min_lat = 12.726084296948185
min_lon = -174.0234375
max_lat = 72.44879155730672
max_lon = -33.3984375
```

The snippet that I've tried:

```py
visible = data.loc[(data.lat < max_lat) & (data.lon > min_lat)] & data.loc[(data.lon > min_lon) & (data.lon < max_lon)]
```

but it failed with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'`

Here is the full code to reproduce this error:

```py
import pandas as pd

col_list = ["country", "capital", "lat", "lon", "code", "continent"]

data = pd.read_csv('countries.csv', error_bad_lines=False, encoding='cp1252', warn_bad_lines=False, sep=';',
                   usecols=col_list, na_filter=False)


min_lat = 12.726084296948185
min_lon = -174.0234375
max_lat = 72.44879155730672
max_lon = -33.3984375

visible = data.loc[(data.lat < max_lat) & (data.lon > min_lat)] & data.loc[(data.lon > min_lon) & (data.lon < max_lon)]

print(visible)
```

So, is there a way to fix this, so I get a list of all the countries that are visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use two `loc`. Only one `loc` should suffice. Assuming that you can read the `csv` properly. You can make use of [`.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and [`.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) as the following:

```
visible = data.loc[(data.lat.lt(max_lat) & data.lat.gt(min_lat)) &
                   (data.lon.lt(max_lon) & data.lon.gt(min_lon))]
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result with [`.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) method:

```
visible = data.loc[(data['lat'].between(min_lat,max_lat, inclusive=False)) &
              (data['lon'].between(min_lon, max_lon, inclusive=False))]
```

Or using no `loc` works too:

```
visible = data[(data.lat.lt(max_lat) & data.lat.gt(min_lat)) &
                   (data.lon.lt(max_lon) & data.lon.gt(min_lon))]
```

```
visible = data[(data['lat'].between(min_lat,max_lat, inclusive=False)) &
              (data['lon'].between(min_lon, max_lon, inclusive=False))]
```

**Output in either case**:

```
                              country           capital        lat        lon code        continent
6                        Saint Martin           Marigot  18.073100 -63.082200   MF    North America
15                           Anguilla        The Valley  18.216667 -63.050000   AI    North America
16                Antigua and Barbuda      Saint John's  17.116667 -61.850000   AG    North America
23                            Bahamas            Nassau  25.083333 -77.350000   BS    North America
26                           Barbados        Bridgetown  13.100000 -59.616667   BB    North America
29                             Belize          Belmopan  17.250000 -88.766667   BZ  Central America
31                            Bermuda          Hamilton  32.283333 -64.783333   BM    North America
37             British Virgin Islands         Road Town  18.416667 -64.616667   VG    North America
45                             Canada            Ottawa  45.416667 -75.700000   CA  Central America
47                     Cayman Islands       George Town  19.300000 -81.383333   KY    North America
62                               Cuba            Havana  23.116667 -82.350000   CU    North America
68                           Dominica            Roseau  15.300000 -61.400000   DM    North America
69                 Dominican Republic     Santo Domingo  18.466667 -69.900000   DO    North America
72                        El Salvador      San Salvador  13.700000 -89.200000   SV  Central America
90                          Greenland              Nuuk  64.183333 -51.750000   GL  Central America
93                          Guatemala    Guatemala City  14.616667 -90.516667   GT  Central America
98                              Haiti    Port-au-Prince  18.533333 -72.333333   HT    North America
100                          Honduras       Tegucigalpa  14.100000 -87.216667   HN  Central America
111                           Jamaica          Kingston  18.000000 -76.800000   JM    North America
142                            Mexico       Mexico City  19.433333 -99.133333   MX  Central America
148                        Montserrat          Plymouth  16.700000 -62.216667   MS    North America
174                       Puerto Rico          San Juan  18.466667 -66.116667   PR    North America
179                  Saint Barthelemy          Gustavia  17.883333 -62.850000   BL    North America
181             Saint Kitts and Nevis        Basseterre  17.300000 -62.716667   KN    North America
182                       Saint Lucia          Castries  14.000000 -61.000000   LC    North America
183         Saint Pierre and Miquelon      Saint-Pierre  46.766667 -56.183333   PM  Central America
184  Saint Vincent and the Grenadines         Kingstown  13.133333 -61.216667   VC  Central America
194                      Sint Maarten       Philipsburg  18.016667 -63.033333   SX    North America
221          Turks and Caicos Islands        Grand Turk  21.466667 -71.133333   TC    North America
232                 US Virgin Islands  Charlotte Amalie  18.350000 -64.933333   VI    North America
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-mark and upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

this lambda expression can help you:

```
visible = data[lambda x: (x['lat']<max_lat) & (x['lon']> min_lat) & (x['lon'] > min_lon) & (x['lon'] < max_lon)]
```